# How to stored the object of array to Shared Preference in Android

Tags: android, json, android-layout, sharedpreferences

I have to store  Id and minimum quantity convert into JSON object of array stored to Share Preference.
I can get the string ID and Min Quantity from JSON object in Volley.Both item have to stored in Shared Preference Array of object as I mentioned below JSON.

Json:(i want to store like this to Shared Preference)

```
{
  [
    "producutid" : 1
    "minqty"     : 5  
  ] 
  ,
  [
    "producutid" : 2
    "minqty"     : 5  
  ]
,  
 [
    "producutid" : 3
    "minqty"     : 5  
  ]
,  
 [
    "producutid" : 4
    "minqty"     : 5  
  ]
```

}

MyWorkingCode:

```
   String channel = shared.getString(Constants.cartid, "{'[]','[]'}");
 JSONArray items = null;
 String wishitem;
 JSONObject jo = null;
 if (TextUtils.isEmpty(channel)) {
     jo = new JSONObject();

     try {
         jo.getJSONArray(String.valueOf(0)).put(String.valueOf(productpathid));
         jo.getJSONArray(String.valueOf(1)).put(String.valueOf(minqty));
     } catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     wishitem = String.valueOf(items);
     editor.putString(Constants.cartid, wishitem);
     editor.apply();

 } else {

     try {

         Boolean found = false;
         jo = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(channel));
         items = jo.getJSONArray(String.valueOf(0));
         for (int x = 0; x < items.length(); x++) {
             if (productpathid.equalsIgnoreCase(items.getString(x))) {
                 found = true;
             }
         }
         if (!found) {
             try {
                 jo.getJSONArray(String.valueOf(0)).put(String.valueOf(productpathid));
                 jo.getJSONArray(String.valueOf(1)).put(String.valueOf(minqty));
             } catch (JSONException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
             wishitem = String.valueOf(items);
             editor.putString(Constants.cartid, wishitem);
             editor.apply();
         }
         editor.apply();

     } catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }}
```

I got error

```
 org.json.JSONException: Value [] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

I did some mistake,can anyone tell me solution for this code.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use Google Gson library to simplify this

Gson Dependency

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
```

**To Store ArrayList of Object in Preference**

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
...
ArrayList<CategoriesEntity> alSelectedCategories = new ArrayList<CategoriesEntity>();
...
String selectedCategory = gson.toJson(alSelectedCategories);
ApplicationPreferences.setValue("SelectedCategory", selectedCategory, activity);
```

**To Get it Back As ArrayList**

```
UserSelectedCategory = ApplicationPreferences.getValue("SelectedCategory", activity);
if (UserSelectedCategory != null) {
       Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<CategoriesEntity>>() {}.getType();
            alSelectedCategories = gson.fromJson(UserSelectedCategory, type);
        }
```

Comment: <categoriesEntity> is a model i don't use model to stored the shared preference

Comment: u can take any datatype u want